how do I lock the screen from anywhere and preserve the current view?
I'd like to lock my app when it goes to the background. And when it becomes active again, and the screen is unlocked (such as via faceID), I'd like to see the most recent view (i.e., the exact state before the app going to the background).
I've tried onChange(scenePhase), but that shows the parent view, Level1, which added the screen lock via navigationDestination, instead of view Level3.
For the example code below, if I pass the State variable, showScreenLock to subsequent views, e.g., Level3 view, and use that to show the screenLock, then it'd work. That means, however, I'd need to pass the State variable to all the views, and that's not practical. Is there a more general solution to meet my need?

    struct ScreenLock: View {
        @State private var showScreenLock = false
        @State private var showNextLayer = true
        
        @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase
        var body: some View {
            Text("Level-1")
                .onChange(of: scenePhase, {
                    print("\(SRC): scenePhase = \(scenePhase)")
                    if (scenePhase == .inactive) || (scenePhase == .background) {
                        showScreenLock = true
                    }
                }) // onChange()
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showScreenLock) {
                    Text("Screen lock")
                }
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showNextLayer) {
                    Level2()
                }
        } // body
        
        struct Level2: View {
            @State private var showNextLevel = true
            
            var body: some View {
                Text(SRC)
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showNextLevel) {
                        Level3()
                    }
            }
        } // Level2
        
        struct Level3: View {
            var body: some View {
                Text("Level-3")
            }
        } // Level3
    } // ScreenLock
    

